Story (webcomic?) where the players shoot a Deck of Many Things at an enemy (a dragon?)
I was reading this question on the RPG Stack Exchange about the best way to introduce the Deck of Many Things in their campaign, and it brought up a fairly vivid memory of a gaming group, knowing that their DM will likely stack the deck against them, deciding to stick the deck on the end of an arrow and shoot it at their enemy in hopes that they'll be overcome by the flurry of random effects (never mind that if their DM was willing to stack the deck before...). My memory is of a webcomic panel, full color, showing the the character (male, dark hair? Medium length. Face uncovered) with the deck impaled on the end of his arrow, about to shoot it towards the fourth wall. Does anyone know what webcomic this might have been from?
The art style in my head is western cartoonish, kind of like Lars DeSouza's Least I Could Do (although I don't think it came from there). I'm pretty sure that it was a dramatic depiction of the roleplaying system by characters in the comic rather than the characters in the adventuring party themselves making the decision.
